# How do I send Username and Password in Login Authentication box for selenium. I cannot locate any elements

Tags: java, selenium

Here is the image.

[image]

I m trying to send the user keys and passwords

Comment: There are already a bunch of similar answers on this website.  Did you search for your answer here?

Answer (score 0):

So I think the problem you are having is it becomes a popup, when a popup occurs you have to tell selenium to go to the pop up, and then type in the username and password data you need from the popup.

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames

There is how to deal with popups and window frames in python. When dealing with a lot of popups I like to do something like this.

```
        #Name of main/first window Selenium invokes
        mainWindow = driver.current_window_handle

        #Switch to first popup
        driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])

        #Switch to main window
        driver.switch_to.window(mainWindow)
```

If it's a javascript alert you have to handle it differently, hope this helps.